# How to stop a slideshow using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, slideshow, transition

Hope you're all doing well. The problem which I am facing at the moment is that I am using a plugin which allows me to do a slideshow of images however I am unable to stop this slideshow and I have no idea on how to do it. The link to the plugin which I am using is - https://www.bestofjqueryplugins.com/plugins/image-slideshow-with-fancy-transitions-effects/ .

It would be great if you could help me out figure out a way to stop this plugin after it has done its slide transitions of the images once. Thanks!

Comment: I have read the library you mentioned. Seems it does not give an interface to pause the autoplay. Maybe you can try other slideshow library like slick. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/55eow2ft/

Comment: oh :( thank you for your help!! @JasmineOT